# How can I quickly mark consecutive lines of the same indentation in Vim?

Tags: visual-mode, nvim

I often edit Python code that needs to be re-indented other otherwise manipulated through visual selection.

Is there any way to visually select all lines of the same indentation in Vim?

I know I could do `V+<n>j` to select the current line and the `<n>` lines below it. However, I don't want to count the lines beforehand.

Furthermore, I have experimented with `V}`, which seem to work, except it doesn't select all lines of there is space between them, and it doesn't select in both directions (up and down).

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I think your best bet is to use a plugin like [vim-indent-object](https://github.com/michaeljsmith/vim-indent-object) it defines some new text objects to handle indentation levels:

[image]

Other alternatives are either:

- Creating your own text objects manually as described [here](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Creating_new_text_objects) which is more or less reimplementing the plugin I mentioned before
- Using a library like [vim-textobj-user](https://github.com/kana/vim-textobj-user) which helps you creating new text objects more easily, but which might be a bit overkill for what you want to do.